# scanning black and white docs leaves dark splotches in white areas

Tags: scanner

I want to scan music that was printed on very clean paper, but my scanner leaves dark splotches in the left margin and between the music staves. In other words, there are dark splotches where there was only whitespace on the original document. I used xsane, "Document Scanner" and gdoc2pdf. They all produced the same result. I tried different settings with brightness, contrast and threshold, but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me whether this is a software problem, or do I need a better scanner?  I have:

- Canon Lide 700 F flatbed scanner.
- Linux 5.3.0-29-generic
- libsane:amd64  1.0.27-3.2ubuntu3 amd64

Comment: Clean the glass of the flatbed first.

Comment: Didn't make any differnece. The glass was already clean. It's essentially signal noise. Or maybe something about the paper and how it reflects light. Either way, the result is pretty unacceptable for document archival.

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al) and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question. Please do not use Add Comment.